# Cannot copy a file from a desktop folder to PostgreSQL (ERROR: relation "us_conties_2010" does not exist SQL state: 42P01)

Tags: postgresql, copy, pgadmin

I am using the Copy command to import a file form a desktop folder into a table a have created on PostgreSQL but it ends up being impossible due to the error in the title.

I am running PgAdmin as administrator and the piece of code I used can be found below:]

```
COPY us_conties_2010
FROM 'C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\practical-sql-master\Chapter_04\us_counties_2010.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: which schema is this table in?

Comment: Either you are connected to the wrong database name, or you didn't specify the correct schema, or the table name is different from what you think. What do you get for `\dt public.*`?

Comment: What does `SHOW search_path;` return?

Comment: Please add your responses as formatted text to your question so folks don't have to work through the comments for relevant information.  Per my previous comment, run `SHOW search_path` in the Query Tool as shown.  Your last error message indicates a file permissions issue. `COPY` runs as the server user and it needs the file to be accessible by that user. Since you are using pgAmin4 I would navigate to the table in the server, right click on it, select the Import/Export item and follow the instructions here [Import/Export](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.5/import_export_data.html)

Comment: The statement 

 `SELECT '\public.*'; `

returns: 

`?column? text \public.*` 

@LaurenzAlbe

Comment: The schema is into public. I just tried `'COPY public.us_counties_2010'` but I got the same error message. @VynlJunkie

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver , your comment about text formating in stackoverflow helped me a lot, thanks.

I tried importing the table navigating in the server, then I received a message to configure my binary path.. I did so and tried again but then I got a pop-up saying: `'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\bin\practical-sql-master\Chapter_04\us_counties_2010.csv\psql.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog `

That was the second time I got the pop-up. After the first time I moved the folder which contais the file to other directory.

Comment: Except your  responses should be added to the original question as updates, not  as comment. This part, `... \us_counties_2010.csv\psql.exe` is wrong, you should not be including `psql.exe` in the file path.